# connecting to an Access database with qt

Tags: qt, ms-access, qsqldatabase

I'm on windows 8 using Qt 4.7.4 (dont ask why :p)
I'm trying to connect to an Access database using this lines of code

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");

db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};FIL={MS Access};DBQ=MSG.accdb");
if (db.open()) {
    qDebug() << "connected";
    return true;
}
else
{
    QSqlError error = db.lastError();
    qDebug() << error.databaseText();
    qDebug() << error.driverText();
    return false;
}
```

Of course it doesn't connect and IQ get the following:

> Application "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\office14\mso.dll" not found in cache
>  "[Microsoft][Pilote
>   ODBC Microsoft Access] Nom de fichier incorrect." 
>  "QODBC3:
>   Unable to connect"

the file MSG.accdb is just at the root of the build folder

I checked the the folder  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\office14\" and I found the MSO.DLL file there.

Comment: Try specifying full absolute path of Access database, not relative path.

Comment: I've already tried that. It didn't work.